# Difficulty starting car: caused by radiator leak?

Tags: starting, radiator, acura, integra

## OBSERVATIONS

95 Acura Integra LS has been emitted a funny smell of cooked chemicals for the last three days after running the vehicle.  Today, there was difficulty starting the car that followed a pattern:

- Cold starts work fine
- Immediate restart after steady-state operation works fine
- Restart after 20 minutes fails: sputters Engine,  restart after 90 minutes wait succesful
- Noticed a steamlike mist when hood was opened.

The radiator reservoir was dry and radiator was extremely low: refilled.  1 hour later a slow leak continues to persist.

## QUESTION

If the radiator or the cooling system has a leak, how can this cause difficulty starting the car?  Is the starter being overheated somehow?  **Simple diagnostics procedures or diagnostic questions are appreciated.**

Comment: What is the temperature gauge on your motor reading at these various times?

Comment: Also, did you look at the oil after stopping?  If you did, was it kind of foamy?

Comment: Well what you've describe suggests that the environment in the engine compartment could get quite humid after a stop. That might cause problems with the spark plugs firing. Over time the residual heat of the engine would dry things out again and the car would start normally again. You could do a rough diagnosis by leaving the hood open after a stop and checking to see if you get a normal start at around 20 minutes. The hood being open should reduce the humidity in the engine compartment after you stop.

Comment: Though about oil pressure? Not sure on that particular car but have seen oil pressure/temperature discrepancies.. can cause delayed starts and in rare cases non start..